# How to change name of input text, when adding more inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

this is the form

```
<form action=""  method="POST">
  <input type="button" value="addmore" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <table id="dataTable" class="TFtable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label>should be auto increment(like (name1, name2, name3 ...))</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" name="DONINID[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />
</form>
```

this is the script to add more => script.js:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 20){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 20.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the idia is how to change the label name too as we add more input box it's should be auto increment like:

name1, name2, name3, name3 and when we add it should show us.

thanks in advance.

Comment: simple form, you can add more input box by clicking on addmore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable that tracks the next # to use and append it to the  contents and  name every time you add one.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="button" value="addmore" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable" class="TFtable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Name 1:</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="name1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var nextName = 2;

function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 20) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = '<label>Name ' + nextName + ':</label>' +
                '<input type="text" required="required" name="name' + nextName + '" />';
            nextName++;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 20.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if (rowCount <= 1) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/4jnw0t09/